# Removing an element not currently in a list: ValueError?

Tags: design, python

This is something that's bothered me for a while, and I can't figure out *why* anyone would ever want the language to act like this:

```
In [1]: foo = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: foo.remove(2) ; foo  # okay
Out[2]: [1, 3]

In [3]: foo.remove(4) ; foo  # not okay?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/izkata/<ipython console> in <module>()

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

If the value is already not in the list, then I'd expect a silent success.  Goal already achieved.  Is there any real reason this was done this way?  It forces awkward code that *should* be much shorter:

```
for item in items_to_remove:
   try:
      thingamabob.remove(item)
   except ValueError:
      pass
```

Instead of simply:

```
for item in items_to_remove:
   thingamabob.remove(item)
```

---

As an aside, no, I can't just use `set(thingamabob).difference(items_to_remove)` because I *do* have to retain both order and duplicates.

Comment: If you want silent success you can use del instead.

Comment: @faif `del foo[foo.index(4)]` -> `ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list`.  Even if I already had a possible index, `del foo[4]` -> `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`.  `del` is just as bad as `.remove()`

Comment: You're right. It seems that there's no way to "silently" remove an item from a list. You can use a list comprehension though: `[x.remove(i) for i in x[:] if i in y]`

Answer (score 4):

From the [Python philosophy](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit

The `.remove()` method has raised an exception from the [very first commit](http://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/896c825f2f71/Objects/listobject.c#550); trying to remove a value that is not there gives you explicit feedback instead of implicitly assuming that the value not being there was fine and what you wanted all along.

Comment: Okay.  So why is it useful?  Just a theoretical from Python's beginnings that was never revisited?

Comment: No, some use-cases require you to know if the item is not there when removing. It could indicate a bug, for example. Just because *your* use-case could be simpler without the exception doesn't mean everyone else has the same use-cases. :-)

Comment: Also, Python has been around for over 20 years. Every single decision in the language has been revisited by now.

Comment: life may easier if `list.remove()` has optional default arg like `.get()`

Answer (score 2):

As an aside: unless your list is extremely large and the list of items to remove is excessively small in comparison, you can create a new list with the items excluded in one readable line:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in source_list if x not in set(items_to_remove)]
```

Obviously it preserves order and duplicates as you want. Very probably it is also faster.

Very often not mutating data greatly simplifies the way you think about an algorithm.